# Monitor which application generate ICMP/ping traffic

Tags: iptables, audit

​
I'm having problem with this,

Something in my system (Linux/Fedora 24/x64) keep sending ping's to several IP address,
and i like to know which process is responsible for this.

I found several articles (and [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/193088)) to use `auditctl` but it didn't work for me.

**Update**: found my problem, see it in the answers below.

---

Comment: I'm guessing you are interested in solutions for Linux, but that might be worth mentioning.

Comment: thanks you are right, just added and updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 2):

#### Part 1:

when trying to debug this with `netstat` i was not able to see any icmp traffic with it, so i tried with `ss`, but even then i didn't see any application, so i tried to run ping to one of my hosts and i was able to see it in the output of `ss -anpw` (`-w` for raw socket)

This is when i returned to wireshark and start looking more closely on the packets, and then it hit me ... (see Part #2).

#### Part 2:

Seems like i miss understand wireshark output, the packets were ICMP, but not echo/reply types but a respond from my Firewall (iptables) to incoming connections.

In my iptables there is this line

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

which will reply with ICMP Type: 3 (Destination unreachable) and Code: 10 (Host administratively prohibited) for any incoming connection which don't match any rule.

It seems that my problem was caused by white-listing the ports for my torrent client, but they were in HOME zone chain, and for some reason my default policy for my Home connection was set to default/public.

After setting the zone for the interface (and having the whitelisted port in the iptable chain) I stop seeing the above ICMP message.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you run:

```
tcpdump -nni ethernet_interface icmp
```

Get the Ethernet_interface by typing `ifconfig`.  It's usually `eth0` (macs use en0). Look for the interface with your IP beside it.

You'll see ICMP echo requests with:

```
IP > Your_IP
```

Once you find the IP that's sending the requests, that page you linked shows how to use `netstat` to find the process ID (pid).  Log into the IP that is sending (if you have rights) and run a `netstat` there.

Comment: Care to elaborate where you get the PID of the program that emits the ICMP packets?

Comment: @Julie Pelletier, I was able to capture this with `ss` and raw sockets, run a ping command to some host and run `ss -anpw` to see it.

Comment: @Rabin:  That does provide a very good answer.  You should make an answer with it.